# Java process.start slows down extremely if parent is not destroyed after launching it

Tags: java, process, exec, freeze, processbuilder

If I start a particular process directly from command line, I see it completely starts in 2-3 seconds.

If I start the exact same process with the exact same command from a Java program, it hangs on start unless the parent is destroyed. Why?

With ProcessBuilder:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.directory(new File(dir));
Process p = pb.start();
```

With Runtime.exec:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, new File(dir));
```

Either way if I do not set the new Process object to null and call the garbage collector right away,the new process takes up to 3 minutes to do the same things it should do in 3 seconds.

```
Process p = pb.start();
p = null;
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Using the code above fixes the issue. Can someone explain me why? I think it's something related to the JVM an process handling but that's just a guess.

The new process uses Hibernate to connect to a MySQL DB, writes logfiles with log4j, reads from a .properties file and connects to a RabbitMQ server.

Thank you,

have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Running external programs from Java applications is notoriously tricky to get right.

I recommend using the high quality [Apache Commons Exec library](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html).

If you want to avoid adding a dependency in your code, at least look at the [Exec library's Java code](http://code.google.com/p/j2exec/source/browse/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.java?spec=svnfe79bd8fbc415740942cafb1e91ed40cbe127564&r=fe79bd8fbc415740942cafb1e91ed40cbe127564) to see how it creates and runs processes.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for an alternative, I'm just curious about why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your child process needs some input from stdin? So it hangs until the input is provided by *p.getOutputStream().write()*

Or it can wait until its stdout will be consumed.

Comment: Nope, I launch the program as "java -jar <program>.jar file.properties". No input is requested ever